# How to avoid hard coding URL when submitting form in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, url-routing, reverse

I have a Django project with a form on the homepage. When the form is submitted, it hard codes a URL which triggers a view function. I am trying to submit that form and trigger the function without hard coding the URL. I have done some research into reverse and reverse_lazy but the actual implementation still makes no sense to me so I am here for help.

index.html:

```
<form action= '/add_trans_form' method="POST" id='formALL'>
```

urls.py

```
app_name ='pages'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index_view, name='index'),
    path('add_trans_form', views.add_trans_form, name='trans_form')
]
```

views.py

```
def add_trans_form(request):
    ~do some top secret stuff to my database~
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pages:index'))
```

please note the project name is AIS and the Django app is 'pages'

PLEASE help me understand what I am doing wrong... I would like to process the form without changing the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) for that:

```
<form action="{% url 'pages:trans_form' %}" method="POST" id='formALL'>
    <!-- … -->
</form>
```

---

> **Note**: You can make use of [**`redirect(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) instead
> of first calling [**`reverse(…)`** [Django]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) and
> then wrap it in a [**`HttpResponseRedirect`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect).
> The `redirect(…)` function does not only offer a more convenient signature to do this, it also for example will use the
> [**`.get_absolute_url()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url)
> if you pass it a model object.
>
> So in your view you can write this as:
>
> ```
> def add_trans_form(request):
>     ~do some top secret stuff to my database~
>     return redirect('pages:index')
> ```

Comment: when I use the url template tag, I get a NoReverseMatch error

Comment: @AustinHallett: but the `name=...` of the view is `trans_form` (as in the `urls.py` included in the question), or `add_trans_form`? The idea is that you pass the name of the view (including the `app_name`), and that Django will resolve this to the corresponding path.

Comment: You're right, I was using the wrong name. That corrected that error! Thanks. Sadly, I am now getting a Disallowed redirect .

Comment: @AustinHallett: this likely has something to do with the `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pages:index'))`. Or another redirect in your view.